# How to disable the email confirmation link after few seconds in php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am sending confirmation e-mail after signup.How can the link be expired after a  few seconds can anyone suggest me.Because if i click on the link after few days also it is getting activated.That should not be happen.Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$sessionCaptcha = $_SESSION['vercode'];
$inputStream = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($inputStream);
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "enjoytax_account", "account") or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("enjoytax_accounting", $connection);
if($db)
{
$confirm_code=md5(uniqid(rand()));
$username = $data->username;
$email = $data->email;
$password = md5($data->password);
$confirmpassword = md5($data->confirmpassword);
$mobileno = $data->mobileno;
$captcha=$data->captcha;    
$check=mysql_query("select email from register where email = '$email'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($check);
if ($num_rows == 0) 
{      
    if($captcha == $sessionCaptcha)
    {   
        $query = mysql_query("insert into register(username,email, password, repassword,mobile,confirm_code) values ('$username','$email', '$password' , '$confirmpassword', '$mobileno','$confirm_code')");

        if ($query)  
          {
              $from .= 'info@mail.com' . "\r\n\r\n";
              $to = $data->email;
              $subject="Your confirmation link here";
              $message.="Click on this link to activate your account \r\n";
              $message.="http://www.example.com/model/confirmation.php?email=$email&passkey=$confirm_code";     
              $success = mail($to, $subject, $message);         
                 $successJson='{"success":"We have sent a verification email ' .
                    'to your email id '.$email.', please check your ' .
                    'Inbox and verify your email in order to proceed further."}';
                print_r($successJson);          
          }else{
            $failureJson='{"error":"We are encountering some issue. Please try after some time."}';
            print_r($failureJson);  
        }
    }else{
    $failureJson='{"error":"Please Enter Correct Captcha."}';       
    print_r($failureJson);  
    }
}else{  
 $failureJson='{"error":"Email-Id already Exists."}';
            print_r($failureJson);
}

}       

?>
```

Comment: Add a `timestamp` column to your `register` table, which records when the link will expire. Then when the link is clicked check if it is after the `timestamp` has expired, and if so, require a new confirmation email/link to be created/sent

Comment: you could use session, let session close and you can remove the link then

Comment: @Rajan can you update the code here so that i can check

Comment: @user6006309 are you using any framework ?? Codeigniter?

Comment: @Rajan No i am not using any framework

Comment: @user6006309 try my updated code that should work

Comment: Hi can anyone help me it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested the code but this might help you.

```
 session_start();

      if ($query)
        {
            $from .= 'info@mail.com' . "\r\n\r\n";
            $to = $data->email;
            $subject="Your confirmation link here";
            $message.="Click on this link to activate your account \r\n";
            $message.="http://www.example.com/model/confirmation.php?email=$email&passkey=$confirm_code";
            $success = mail($to, $subject, $message);
            $successJson='{"success":"We have sent a verification email ' .
                'to your email id '.$email.', please check your ' .
                'Inbox and verify your email in order to proceed further."}';

            $_SESSION['now'] = date('i:s');

            $now =date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            $futureDate = $now+(60*5);

            $formatDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $futureDate);

            if($_SESSION['now'] > $formatDate)
            {
                $failureJson='{"error":"We are encountering some issue. Please try after some time."}';
                 print_r($failureJson);       

            }

        }
        else
        {

            echo " Query Not Executed";
        }
```

Comment: Need to create  column in database.what is link_status

Comment: Its a session variable that will check is the current time greater than the time we set the session

Comment: No it is not working for the first time i have activated my mail if i click the same link after few seconds it is working

Comment: did you start the session ?

Comment: @user6006309 try this code and let me know if you see any error i

Comment: Getting error as error occured while creating account i have started session

Comment: where are you getting error? line number? use the updated code.

Comment: Getting error message is undefined and data is inserting into database.but the link is working for twice or thrice

Comment: @It is inserting the data but the link is working for many times

Comment: @user6006309 it was my mistake see the updated the code we check if session is not set then show error message

Comment: No i am not getting any error but the link is working for so many times

Comment: Updated my total Code can you please check it once

Comment: @user6006309 wait i will post an answer

Comment: @user6006309 after what time do you want to expire your link ?

Comment: After 5 mins the link should expire

Comment: We are encountering some issue. Please try after some time.getting this error

Comment: @user6006309 you are seeing the error we have set in the code please understand the code.if current time is greater than the time we set at sending email we show error

Comment: the data should insert into database once the insertion is done will be sending email when the user click the email account will be activated,after activation if the user clicks the link again it is working it should not work this is my problem

Comment: Do you have team viewer?@user6006309

Comment: Give me your email id i will be sending you the details